# ifort: error #10001: could not find directory in which g++ resides

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I am going to compile a fortran code with ifort, but I received the following error:
((ifort: error #10001: could not find directory in which g++ resides))
Note: on my system g++ was installed.

Could you please help me in this way?

Comment: whereis g++: g++: /usr/bin/g++ /usr/share/man/man1/g++.1.gz

Comment: If a working g++ is on PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH you should be ok.  If you installed g++ development system on 64 bit Linux it would take care of intel64 compiler only.

Comment: I added tag intel-fortran to attract someone from Intel but it may be a good idea to ask at their support forum instead anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Tips for resolving this are in https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-fortran-compiler-for-linux-ifort-error-could-not-find-directory-in-which-g-resides